# Slow network connection on Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: networking, 22.04, internet, connection

Recently, I changed my OS from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 22.04.3 and I noticed that my internet was too slow compared to Windows, I spent hours downloading simple files or installing some things on the computer. When I bought my computer (a few years ago) I installed Ubuntu 22.04, I used it for a while (everything worked fine) and then switched to Windows, now I have switched back to Ubuntu and my internet seems to be extremely slow. I have no idea what is going on and how to fix this problem. I mean, my internet is not perfect, but it is now extremely terrible now for no reason.

Comment: how do you configure network interfaces? what if you add an additional DNS server (e.g. 8.8.8.8)?